# security risk of scripts in ooxml word document

Tags: c#, openxml

I am considering a feature of a service I am developing but am worried about malicious code injection. The service is a simple merge of a dataset and a docx file.

I have a requirement for aggregate merge codes and the only solution I have come to with is to use ooxml. This works great but I am worried that if an attacker discovered this they can insert scripts to do evil.

Is there a way to harden my system against this kind of injection or is it even possible for someone to exploit the system in this way?

I don't know that code is necessary here but if so I can provide it. Essentially I have a function that figures out if the string is XML, attempts to parse it as such and if it's good then uses the openxml frameworks openxmlreader class to turn it into an openxmlelement. That is then inserted into the document replacing the merge field placeholder.

Comment: This would probably get better answers at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I considered that but this has to do with code specifically and that site is usually more about configuration.

Comment: Word and OpenXML are more my area of expertise, so I'm not exactly following where in your process you feel there could be a security risk? Are you thinking "someone" could insert something into the Word document that could be malicious?

Comment: It's not possible to insert an executable script into the Word document, itself. Executable script would be VBA - that's in binary format, must be inserted into the Zip package as a PART, with corresponding relationships and the document TYPE and the file extension would need to be changed. Other than that, there are some field codes that have potential to access external files, but Word will NOT update (execute) them on opening a document without user approval. I'd think your code could check the document for undesirable content, or things your code didn't insert, if that's a real concern.

Comment: @Cindy Meister thanks for confirming my suspicions. I figured with the way word secures scripts (I did mean vba) I would be safe but am not super experienced with this. I was worried about the merge data containing a script in cdata and that getting inserted into my resulting document. If it is true that it must be a "part" of the package then I should be fine. Thanks again.

Comment: Since you confirm that your concern was VBA I've put the text of my comment into an "Answer" in order to help SO "admin" (the Q&A concept of the site) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that your concern is for the danger of executable "script" (VBA) being inserted into a docx file during editing of the file's Open XML.

VBA (macros) are contained in separate "Parts" in the document's ZIP package. They must be in proprietary, binary format, must be inserted into the Zip package as one or more PART files, with corresponding relationships. In addition the document TYPE and the file extension would need to be changed.

So there's no danger of malicious code being able to insert executable script into the XML strings being written to any XML part of the document package.

Other than that, there are some field codes that have potential to access external files, but Word will NOT update (execute) them on opening a document without user approval. I'd think your code could check the document for undesirable content, or things your code didn't insert, if that's a real concern.

Comment: Thanks, This answers my concerns. I may add some code to check the templates (.docx) files for any vba just in case.

Comment: As long as the file is a .docx no macro code can execute. As a matter of fact, Word won't even open a file with the extension docx if it contains macros  - it will consider the content to be "damaged".